# Mosaic `st_buffer` doesn't return geometry of type Point or Polygon

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, geospatial

I am expecting to create a buffer around `point` geometry that would be of `Polygon` type. For example, I run the following code to obtain the geometries.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (37.775, -122.418),
    (40.714, -74.006),
    (41.007, 28.613),
], ["lat", "long"])


df1 = df.withColumn("point_geom", st_point("lat", "lng"))
df1.select('point_geom').show(5)

--------------------+
|          point_geom|
+--------------------+
|{1, 0, [[[32.4374...|
|{1, 0, [[[32.4374...|
|{1, 0, [[[32.4374...|
|{1, 0, [[[32.4374...|
|{1, 0, [[[32.4374...|


df2 = df1.withColumn("geom_buffer", st_buffer("point_geom", lit(.2)))
df2.select('geom_buffer').show(5)

--------------------+
|         geom_buffer|
+--------------------+
|{5, 4326, [[[32.6...|
|{5, 4326, [[[32.6...|
|{5, 4326, [[[32.6...|
|{5, 4326, [[[32.6...|
|{5, 4326, [[[32.6...|
+--------------------+
```

1. Why are these not `Point` or of `Polygon` type? How do we convert them to geometry type?
2. What is the unit of `radius` in `st_buffer`? It is not clear from the docs.
3. What do the numbers in `{1,  0} {5, 4326}` represent?

https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/api/spatial-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

st_point in mosaic <= 0.3.11 is returning an internal representation of a geometry.
If you wrap st_point into st_astext you will get the right outputs.
The internal representation for st_ expressions in mosaic will be deprecated from 0.4.x.

```
df1 = df.withColumn("point_geom", st_astext(st_point("lat", "lng")))
df2 = df1.withColumn("geom_buffer", st_buffer("point_geom", lit(.2)))
df2.display()
```